# Не получается стилизовать видео в модальном окне

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте!
Не могу расположить видео по центру и увеличить, нужно сделать его +- вот такого размера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.modal-content2,
.modal-body2 {
  background: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}

.modal-header,
.modal-footer {
  border: none;
}

.close,
.close:hover {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-body2 iframe {
  width: 1000px;
  border: none;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a href="#modalvideo" class="videomodal" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<div id="modalvideo" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content2">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body2">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Dq9eLgyuD1k" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Сайт: http://tvarinskydesign.16mb.com/pura/

Answer (score 0):

У тебя на сайте есть такой код `css`:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .modal-dialog {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 30px auto;
  }
}
```

Убери оттуда `width:600px`;

И добавь стиль `text-align: center;` для блока с классом `.modal-body2`, оно родитель твоего `iframe`, где находиться видео.

И тогда получишь вот такой вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]